# Access object value through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be simple but not sure on how to finish this off. I have the following array of JS objects for example

```
// JS Objects
var businessObject = [{name: "Tesco", location: "Cardiff"}, {name: 'IAC', location: 'Newport'}, {name: "Specsavers", location:"Southampton"}]
```

i then have a function that will loop through and pick an object at random

```
// Functions
randomObject = function() {
  var random = businessObject[Math.floor(Math.random()*businessObject.length)]; 
  return random;
};
```

I then want to assign one of the values to an input field by running the function

```
 $('#name').val(randomObject());
```

But how do i just pick out the location for example of the random object generated

at the moment I get [object Object] returned

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qimed/1/edit)**

```
$('#name').val(randomObject().location);
```

if you `return` an Object literal, from the function `randomObject()` simply access the desired *property* using *dot notation.*

---

[**Another way**](http://jsbin.com/qimed/3/edit) to make your Function more reusable is to pass a desired Array of objects to the function argument:

```
function rand( arr ) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]; 
}

$('#name').val( rand(businessObject).location );
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on making the function more reusable, that helps a lot